# Mac: I get SIGABRT but the call stack is useless

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, callstack

I'm coding a game for Mac in c++, and I'm getting a SIGABRT, and the console prints the following:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
  what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

So, I'm doing a bad lexical_cast. But the problem is that I can't know where, because the call stack is as follows:

```
#0  0x7fff85fb629a in mach_msg_trap
#1  0x7fff85fb690d in mach_msg
#2  0x7fff81f58932 in __CFRunLoopRun
#3  0x7fff81f57dbf in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#4  0x7fff88dba7ee in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
#5  0x7fff88dba5f3 in ReceiveNextEventCommon
#6  0x7fff88dba4ac in BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode
#7  0x7fff84f85e64 in _DPSNextEvent
#8  0x7fff84f857a9 in -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
#9  0x7fff84f4b48b in -[NSApplication run]
#10 0x7fff84f441a8 in NSApplicationMain
#11 0x1000ef759 in os_gameMainLoop at main-osx.mm:22
#12 0x10009a97d in main at words.cpp:18
```

That´s not the right stack.

What's match_msg_trap?
Whay am I getting this call stack?
Do I have any way to get a good call stack on the crash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger stopped in the wrong thread. Try `t a a bt` in GDB to see backtraces for all the threads.

`mach_msg_trap` is where threads park while they are waiting for a message to come in. So, you are looking at a thread that isn't running. Mach is the name of the message-passing interface on OS X.